# Do cronjobs have better performance than sleep functions?

Tags: python, performance, cron, sleep

I'm running a miner on my Raspberry Pi at 100% CPU performance. I want the Raspberry Pi to send some tweets about his temperature and Hashrate over twitter. So far I've written a script which does its job well... To keep the miners performance it's important for me which method consumes less power/performance.

What would you use? Cronjobs or sleep?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cronjobs should be more efficient. There are always being check out by the system, if you use sleep you would be still checking for cronjobs (even if there's no job to run) so sleep is innecesary.

Comment: Actually I would beg to differ. The main advantage with cronjobs is that if the process dies it will run again next time, but a sleep avoids creating a new process every time and thus should have less overhead. Plus cron can be disabled if the system is dedicated to one task. Running unnecessary services just consumes power. Disable all services/daemons that are not needed.